# Don't understand why inner join is necessary for filtering in sql

Tags: sql, join

I have the following tables:

Basically I have a many2many relation between students and courses using the junction table students_courses

[image]

Here is some data populated into the tables:
students:

[image]

courses

[image]

students_courses:

[image]

So basically I would like to select the full_name and c_id for a given student. So for example for student with id=3 i would have Aurica 5 and Aurica 6.

My first approach was to write:

```
select s.full_name,sc.c_id from students s, students_courses sc
where sc.s_id=3
```

But i obtain this:

```
Aurica 5
Aurica 6
Aurica 5
Aurica 6
Aurica 5
Aurica 6
```

So it is duplicated by the number of rows of the students_courses table. Now I'm not sure why this happens.

If I would be an SQL parser, I would parse it like this:
"take the c_id from students_courses, full_name from students, and display them if the students_course row respects the where filter"

Not it works using join, but I don't really understand why the inner join is necessary.

```
select s.full_name, sc.c_id from students s
inner join students_courses sc
on sc.s_id=s.id and s.id=3;
```

Explain a bit how is the first sql interpreted by the SQL parser and why with join works.

Thanks,

Comment: This is not a site for learning the basics of SQL.  There are many books, videos, online resources, and courses that provide this information.

Comment: When did either SQL or basic programming questions become off limits at Stackoverflow?  In my experience this issue is generally glossed over in introductory literature -- you're shown *how* to JOIN tables, but not necessarily told why you need to.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff: I don't want to learn SQL. I want to understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select information from two tables what it does is a cross product of all the records and then it looks to the all of the records that satisfy the where clause. You have 3 records in the Students table

```
id | full_name
---+----------
3  | Aurica
4  | Aurica
5  | Aurica
```

And 6 records in the student_courses table.

```
s_is | c_id
-----+-----
3    | 5
3    | 6
4    | 7
4    | 8
5    | 9
5    | 10
```

So before your where statement it creates 18 different records. So it is easy to see I will include all of the columns.

```
s.id | s.full_name | sc.s_id | sc.c_id
-----+-------------+---------+--------
3    | Aurica      | 3       | 5
3    | Aurica      | 3       | 6
3    | Aurica      | 4       | 7
3    | Aurica      | 4       | 8
3    | Aurica      | 5       | 9
3    | Aurica      | 5       | 10
4    | Aurica      | 3       | 5
4    | Aurica      | 3       | 6
4    | Aurica      | 4       | 7
4    | Aurica      | 4       | 8
4    | Aurica      | 5       | 9
4    | Aurica      | 5       | 10
5    | Aurica      | 3       | 5
5    | Aurica      | 3       | 6
5    | Aurica      | 4       | 7
5    | Aurica      | 4       | 8
5    | Aurica      | 5       | 9
5    | Aurica      | 5       | 10
```

From there it only displays the ones where cs.id=3

```
s.full_name | sc.c_id
------------+--------
Aurica      | 5
Aurica      | 6
Aurica      | 5
Aurica      | 6
Aurica      | 5
Aurica      | 6
```

The second query you had compared the value of sc.s_id=s.id and only displays the ones where those values are the same, as well as the c_id=3

Answer (score 2):

The SQL parser doesn't try to guess how your two tables are related. It would seem like the database engine has enough information to figure this out itself by following constraints, but SQL intentionally doesn't use the FK relationships to decide how to join your tables; you might want to remove constraints at at future date for some reason (such as in order to improve performance), and you wouldn't want dropping a constraint to alter how joins were made. The DBA needs freedom to change indexes and constraints without having to worry about having changed what results are returned by queries.

Since it can't count on having complete information to go on, the SQL engine is not in the business of deducing/guessing relationships. It's up to the person writing the SQL to specify what they are joining on. If you don't give it any instructions telling it how to hook up the tables (using a JOIN ON clause or WHERE clause) then it creates a cross join, which gives you the duplicated results.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  *You*, as a human being, instinctively make the connection that the tables must be related by the commonly-named columns, but the SQL engine purposely does not make any such assumptions.  Your assumption is a reasonable one for simple cases, but when your model becomes richer, and students have relationships among each other (such as adviser / advisee) it becomes impossible to guess the correct relationship.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, SQL is a set-based language, you operate on sets of data, not on single (rows of) data.

> If I would be an SQL parser, I would parse it like this: "take the
>   c_id from students_courses, full_name from students, and display them
>   if the students_course row respects the where filter"

Here, you're overlooking the sets *students_courses* and *students*, and just thinking about each row of data, like *if this rows respects the filter, give me all the informations*.

The `JOIN` doesn't filter data (that's what `WHERE` does), but instead it *puts it together*.

When you `SELECT` from table A, you ask for the set of rows in A, all of them.
When you `SELECT` from table A `WHERE` some condition, you ask for the set of rows in A that *respect the condition* (so the SQL engine discards rows from A that do not belong to the set you *described* with your query).

When you `JOIN` table_a and table_b, you ask to join the set of rows in a with the set of rows in b, obtaining a new set whose rows are the "concatenation" (let me use that term) of the columns from a row in A and the columns from a row in B; this, without giving any other information about *how* to join the rows, simply results in each row of table_a *joined* with each row of table_b.

That's why you don't get what you expect.

Finally, from a conceptual point of view, I'd like to point out that the SQL engine doesn't take the columns you request from a table or another, but after (1) having *joined* the rows in any table you requested and (2) having filtered out any row that doesn't match the *where* condition, it just return the columns you requested from the rows of the resulting set after (1) and (2).
In real life, RDBMS may reorder these operations, and apply any kind of optimization they find possible based on indexes and other query and tables informations they have available.

This should give you a rough idea of what's going on. But as @GordonLinoff suggested you, I think you should get a stronger basis about SQL and relational databases before you go any further, or it will get harder than this.

As a side note, what you had in your `FROM` clause, is a sort of *implicit join*, a former join syntax in which the `FROM` clause specifies the tables involved, and the `WHERE` clause the join predicate (the columns whose values should match to *join* the data).

Comment: I think another point to add is that *some* RDBMS have implicit joins, which I'm sure seemed like a good idea at the time, but can cause confusion.

Comment: @watery: You are incorrect about the order in which the SQL engine performs filtering, column selection, and joining.  That order will depend on the columns referenced in the filtering conditions, the presence of indexes, the and contents of those indexes both row wise (how many different index values are in the table) and column wise (for index-only optimized retrieval).  In the example given the engine will almost certainly filter the student_courses before performing the JOIN.

Comment: @ckuhn203: I'm not aware of a single SQL-based RDMS that supports explicit JOINs but not implicit ones.  Can you suggest any?

Comment: @LarryLustig Of course, mine is not a technical explanation, but a conceptual one. I'll revise it anyhow, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you would have done something like

```
select s.full_name,sc.c_id 
from students s, students_courses sc
where sc.s_id = s.id  --<-- you left this out
AND sc.s_id=3
```

You would have got the same results, Inner join is not necessary for this statement but it is a good practice to use this newer INNER JOIN Syntax to retrieve data.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your queries are in fact joins, only in your first example there is no word "join" (but it is there, trust me).

However, that's an **old style join** and it's not recommended to use any more. In short, it's about NULL values - this old style join has an problem with interpreting NULL values and that's why you have wrong result.

For more details see [here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/old-join-syntax-vs-new).

Comment: There are two errors in this answer: the problem with the query has nothing to do with whether an implicit or explicit JOIN is used (you can produce a Cartesian product with either form) and NULL interpretation is also not involved in the results observed by the OP.

Comment: @Larry: Sorry, my mistake, it's not related to NULL value in this example.